# substring a variable in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, build, version, pom.xml

Is it possible (and how) to substring a variable in the pom.xml, or the properties that uses this variable?

**My scenario:**

I have a swing application that shows a kind of version in its footer.
This version is read from a properties file.
The properties file only have a reference for a maven variable, as:

```
version=${git.branch}
```

In my pom.xml, a have a plugin that looks for the branch name, and write it in the "git.branch" variable.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../.git</dotGitDirectory>
                <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/version.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/version.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

But now we are using a prefix for the branch names, and this prefix shouldn't be deployed with the application version.

I had branches like:

```
v123
v124
v125
```

Now I have branches like:

```
b_04_v123
b_04_v124
```

And i want maven to get only the value "v124" of the string "b_04_v123", the prefix is fixed, aways like "b_NN_".

NOTE: No, it's not possible to change the branch names, as other departments uses them with scripts and automation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it inside the java code, I already had a code reading the properties file, just added the substring there.
It isn't a beautiful maven solution, but worked. I could have done this since the beginning.
But, if someone could tell how can I substring a variable in my pom.xml it would be great, although I don't need it anymore (or with the same urgency) I'm still curious.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `org.codehaus.groovy.maven` plugin:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>                  
System.setProperty("version2","${version}".replace('b_04_', ''))
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

and now you can use version2 :

```
version=${version2}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I couldn't get this to work, my maven and dependencies did not accepted this plugin well. But I just solved it in the java code that reads the properties file, why haven't I thought of it earlier?

Comment: Incase someone wants to use this new variable in POM itself, use - project.properties.setProperty(.......)

Comment: Can't get ${git.branch} value in gmaven-plugin.

Comment: @GreenLei if ${git.branch} is a global variable than you can use it insread of "version2"

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question myself and the other provided answers did not work for me. So I created my own Maven plugin.
It can [search and replace other variables or normal text using regular expressions and so create a new variable](https://github.com/1tchy/variable-search-replace-plugin).
For your case it would be something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.github.1tchy</groupId>
    <artifactId>variable-search-replace-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <text>${git.branch}</text>
                <search>^b_\d\d_</search>
                <variableName>old.version</variableName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you can simply use it as a normal property: `version=${old.version}`

The plugin can also define a replacement text: check out its [documentation](https://github.com/1tchy/variable-search-replace-plugin)!